# Significato di "tracca"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Una bacheca rigurgitante di avvisi e biglietti cattura lo sguardo di Diamante. Questo seminterrato deve essere una specie di agenzia di collocamento perché quegli avvisi sono offerte di lavoro. Cercasi 50 minatori per la contea di Lackawanna. 500 uomini per lavoro di **tracca**, Compagnia Erie presso Buffalo e Youngstown.

Qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare cosa significa "tracca" in questo brano? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo nei dizionari che ho consultato.

Comment: L'unica accezione che ho trovato che potrebbe avere senso nel contesto è in questo [dizionario Italiano-Sardo](https://books.google.it/books?id=G-RGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA582&lpg=PA582&dq=lavoro+di+tracca&source=bl&ots=QCUflM81u7&sig=m2T1dntN7izVKeIdc38PpvIgzlI&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPk4uz-t3fAhUw1uAKHbpXCPA4ChDoATAAegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=lavoro%20di%20tracca&f=false) secondo cui il termine tracca deriva dall'italiano [trabacca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trabacca/) che significa _Con sign. più generico, palco o altra struttura di assi di legno, soprattutto se poco stabile_

Comment: @abarisone quindi sostanzialmente, carpentieri.

Comment: Esatto carpentieri in legno

Comment: @abarisone sulla base di quello che hai scritto direi che l'avviso cercava persone per lavori di carpenteria in legno, probabilmente per edificare strutture temporanee.

Comment: Butto lì un'ipotesi senza alcuna pezza d'appoggio: non sarà un'italianizzazione a orecchio di _track_, così come gli immigrati italiani parlavano di “Broccolino” (Brooklyn) e “carro” (_car_)? Sarebbe compatibile con il contesto?

Comment: @DaG: È perfettamente possibile. Si tratta di italiani emigrati agli Stati Uniti. Ed ecco un'altra frase del libro: «I ragazzi però lo sfottono comunque, e dicono che presto Celestina diventerà la gherla piú carina di Mulberry».

Comment: @DaG: Infatti, ecco come continua il brano: «200 uomini per lavoro di spianamento strada. Paga 2 dollari e 50. Un cuoco per una squadra di addetti alle ferrovie in West Virginia. 30 sterratori per la Lehigh Valley Railroad. Fiori artificiali: cercansi 20 donne branciste Meehan 687 Broadway. 4 sticcatrici di foglie 2 ramidatrici, 26 Waverly Place. Drappers finishers binders Mack Kanner & Milius. Venti muratori, tre carradori, sette fuochisti, dieci tagliatori di granito, due conduttori di caldaie a vapore.»

Comment: Ci sono altre parole che non capisco e che non trovo nei dizionari. Adesso penso che possano anche trattarsi dell'italianizzazione di termini inglesi (ma non so veramente quali).

Comment: @Charo: Già, sembra che la tracca da seguire sia proprio questa!

Comment: A quanto pare, la ["Compagnia Erie"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erie_Railroad) era una società ferroviaria.

Comment: @DaG: Da quanto si può leggere in [questo documento](https://www.tesionline.it/mobile/tesi/brano/Italoamericano/9915), sembra si tratti di un termine italoamericano proveniente dalla deformazione di "truck". Infatti, più avanti nel romanzo, si spiega come gli operai che stanno costruendo le linee ferroviarie nell'Ohio siano distribuiti in diversi campi di lavoro.

Comment: Diamante, uno dei protagonisti del romanzo (il nonno dell'autrice, infatti), lavora come "waterboy" in uno di questi campi e si spiega come tutti i lavoratori del campo dormivano in "un vagone merci in disuso da quando le locomotive andavano a legna". A un certo punto appare l'espressione "la tracca dei dago", credo che per riferirsi a questo vagone. E un po' più avanti si può leggere in riferimento a una metodista che si è offerta a insegnare l'inglese ai lavoratori della ferrovia:

Comment: "Purtroppo i dago non si dimostrano interessati ai vantaggi della lingua americana, e lei sarà costretta a offrire i suoi tesori alla tracca degli ucraini, degli ungheresi o dei finnici" (suppongo che per riferirsi ai "vagoni-dormitorio" di altri campi di lavoro).

Comment: Grazie per l'aggiornamento, @Charo.

Comment: @DaG o  a Charo... Acclarato che è un caso simile a "crossa la stritta" per dire attraversa la strada (cross the street)... direi che oramai sarebbe il caso di scriverlo come risposta... `:-)`

Comment: @Hastur:    Forse si potrebbe scrivere la risposta che stai suggerendo, il problema è che non mi è ancora del tutto chiaro se si tratta di una deformazione di "truck" oppure di "track".

Answer (score 1):

Sulla tesi di laurea di Eleonora Tavera intitolata ["Lessico dialettale e italoamericano nella traduzione spagnola di *Vita* di Melania Mazzucco"](https://www.tesionline.it/mobile/tesi/brano/Italoamericano/9915), diretta da Luigi Matt, ho trovato che si tratta di un termine italoamericano proveniente dalla deformazione di "truck".

Ho anche visto che la ["Compagnia Erie"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erie_Railroad) era una società ferroviaria.

Il termine "tracca" torna a apparire parecchie volte molto più avanti nel romanzo, in una parte del libro che spiega come gli operai che stanno costruendo le linee ferroviarie dell'Ohio siano distribuiti in diversi campi di lavoro. Il contesto dove appare è in effetti compatibile con il fatto che  "tracca" significhi "truck" nel senso di treno o vagone ferroviario. Diamante, uno dei protagonisti del romanzo (il nonno dell'autrice, infatti), lavora come "waterboy" in uno di questi campi e si menziona come tutti i lavoratori del campo dormono in

> un vagone merci in disuso da quando le locomotive andavano a legna.

A un certo punto appare l'espressione "la tracca dei dago", nel passo seguente:

> A luglio, quando il sole arroventa il vagone, e sembra di dormire in una fornace, si presenta una zitella metodista desiderosa di insegnare l’inglese agli “uomini di bronzo”. Diamante chiede se deve pagare qualcosa, e Miss Olivia Campbell gli risponde che il corso è gratuito. I generosi parrocchiani di Lima vogliono aiutare gli stranieri a integrarsi nella nostra nazione. Diamante spiega che al corso s’iscriverebbe pure, ma è cattolico. Fu battezzato e fece la prima comunione. La cresima no, perché se ne venne in America. La zitella sorride. Avrà quarant’anni. È secca come una foglia, con i capelli rossi. Ha fegato, per essere venuta tutta sola alla **tracca** dei dago – che gli americani considerano degli incalliti stupratori.

Fa pensare che "la tracca dei dago" possa riferirsi a questo vagone, menzionato all'inizio del passaggio. E un po' più avanti si può leggere in riferimento a questa metodista che si è offerta a insegnare l'inglese ai lavoratori della ferrovia

> Purtroppo i dago non si dimostrano interessati ai vantaggi della lingua americana, e lei sarà costretta a offrire i suoi tesori alla **tracca** degli ucraini, degli ungheresi o dei finnici

per riferirsi, a quanto pare, ai "vagoni-dormitorio" di altri campi di lavoro.

Tuttavia, come hanno detto DaG e egreg nei suoi commenti, "tracca" potrebbe anche essere la deformazione dell'inglese ["track"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_(rail_transport)) perché molto probabilmente la costruzione dei diversi rami delle linee ferroviarie erano affidate ai gruppi di lavoratori ("i dago", "gli ucraini", "gli ungheresi", "i finnici", ecc.) di cui parla il testo.

Comment: Il femminile mi fa pensare più a *track* che a *truck*. I lavori ferroviari erano divisi in tronchi, spesso assegnati a gruppi omogenei di immigrati.

Comment: @egreg:   Ecco un brano del libro: «A luglio, quando il sole arroventa il vagone, e sembra di dormire in una fornace, si presenta una zitella metodista desiderosa di insegnare l’inglese agli “uomini di bronzo”. [...] Avrà quarant’anni. È secca come una foglia, con i capelli rossi. Ha fegato, per essere venuta tutta sola alla tracca dei dago – che gli americani considerano degli incalliti stupratori.»

Comment: Da questo brano, ho pensato che "la tracca" fosse lo stesso che "il vagone", ma forse hai ragione che potrebbe essere anche "track". Cercherò di aggiornare la risposta.

Comment: @egreg: Comunque, non capisco cosa ha a che vedere con il fatto che sia un sostantivo femminile.

Comment: So che non si tratta di una risposta definitiva alla domanda, ma perlomeno raccoglie il contenuto di tutti i commenti.

Comment: @Charo La lingua (italiana) è un'entità viva - anche se noi tutti ne attentiamo l'integrità di quando in quando `:-)`. Come entità viva, la lingua muta, si evolve, si trasforma. Talvolta nascono neologismi (o in questo caso forme dialettali nuove): alcuni sopravvivono solo qualche tempo prima di cadere nell'oblio (vedi `matusa` nella Treccani), altri al contrario finiscono per aggermarsi nell'uso corrente... Non credo possa esistere una risposta definitiva `:-)`, ed anche qualora ci fosse la si potrebbe spiegare in modi diversi...

Comment: @Charo Riguardo al maschile e al femminile; capita, nel provare a parlare una lingua che non si conosce abbastanza bene, di modificare una parola in un suono più _naturale_ e di concordarla con il genere della sua traduzione nella propria lingua. Per esempio, "attraversa la strada" -- "cross the street" --> (tu) crossa la stritta. Nota __la__ stritta e non lo stritto perché in Italiano la strada è al femminile. Anche se [non sempre è così](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/genere-dei-forestierismi/1229) per quelle che rimangono...

Comment: Questo lo so, @Hastur, ma "tracca" intesa come "track" a quale parola femminile italiana corrisponderebbe?

Comment: @Charo Direi “zona di lavoro”, femminile; al contrario, “vagone” è maschile e darebbe “il tracco”.

Comment: @egreg: Ho visto che "track" nel senso ferroviario di solito si traduce come "binario". Potrebbe essere forse "ferrovia". Lo dico per quello di "500 uomini per lavoro di tracca, Compagnia Erie presso Buffalo e Youngstown" che appare nella domanda.

Comment: Da: http://www.sscrocifisso.vv.it/archivio/speciali/Plabarcunata/barcunata2008/natale2008/La%20Barcunatadicembre1xx.pdf : *Così –non potendo certo aspettare lì per un intero anno- camminano tracca, tracca, cioè lungo la ferrovia, seguendo i binari, finché non chiedono ad un
policemen: “Che ora è”? E quello risponde (secondo
loro): “Levan a krac”. E il nostro esperto traduce,
disperato: “Oh cazzu, mo levanu la tracca”!
Per rendere la vita difficile al povero emigrante sono
capaci addirittura di smontare i binari*

Comment: Molto interessante. Grazie, @magma!